# An internal error occurred during: "Requesting Java AST from selection com.ibm.icu.text.UTF16.isSurrogate(C)Z" in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Whenever I am trying to open any Java file in Eclipse I am getting "An internal error occurred during: "Requesting Java AST from selection" com.ibm.icu.text.UTF16.isSurrogate(C)Z". I am using Eclipse 2020-03.
Please help me

I tried with disabling the occurrences but it is not a long time solution.

Comment: Eclipse 2020-03 is more than 3 years and 13 releases behind. Please upgrade. Please support the open source software you use by not asking questions about outdated versions, but about the latest version only (which is currently 2023-06, and next week it will be 2023-09).

Comment: Probably related to [this issue](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator/issues/476) and should be fixed in the current Eclipse.